# Rails stuck in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, passenger, yarnpkg

I am in the process of deploying my Rails application with Passenger and when I run this command to get my application ready and set for production I get this yarn message but no further actions are run.

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

Output from that command:

```
yarn install v1.3.2
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
info Lockfile not saved, no dependencies.
Done in 0.04s.
```

When this is finished running I hop into the Rails console and run `Rails.env` and the result is development. I have removed and re-installed Yarn but that is no luck. There are no Yarn dependencies so I am confused as to why I need it in the first place. If I run the `bundle exec` command without Yarn installed I get this message:

```
Yarn executable was not detected in the system.
Download Yarn at https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install
```

Does anybody know how to by-pass this or set this to production mode without having Yarn installed?

I have also tried running:

`RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

But get this rather large input:

```
/var/www/isharelessons/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::RUBY
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:10: warning: previous definition of RUBY was here
/var/www/isharelessons/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: already initialized constant FileUtils::LN_SUPPORTED
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:109: warning: previous definition of LN_SUPPORTED was here
/var/www/isharelessons/code/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: already initialized constant Rake::FileUtilsExt::DEFAULT
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/lib/rake/file_utils_ext.rb:17: warning: previous definition of DEFAULT was here
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#ext already exists
WARNING: Possible conflict with Rake extension: String#pathmap already exists
[....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a command like

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

It will use the production environment when executing those commands, but it doesn't put you in the environment beyond the duration of that single rake command. If you then run

```
$ rails c
2.4.2 :001 > Rails.env
 => "development"
```

It's showing `development`, because `RAILS_ENV` is empty, and when empty, the default environment is development.

When you specify an environment on the command line at the end of a rake command, it doesn't change the shell's environment; it's just an argument to the rake command, and does not persist in any way.

Similarly, when you prefix a command with the environment, like

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

It does not persist beyond that single command. It's a temporary variable assignment. That does change the shell variable, but only for the duration of that command line, and it also does not change the environment for future commands.

If you want to set the environment for your shell session, so that it affects all future commands (until you log out or start a new shell), then you have to export the variable:

```
$ export RAILS_ENV=production
$ rails c
2.4.2 :001 > Rails.env
 => "production"
```